# Printf width, unexpected format results

Tags: java

I have the code here:

```
double n = 1234.56789;

System.out.printf("n=%8.2e", n);
```

Which prints out `n=1.23e+03`

I have read a few formatting manuals for printf, and I can't seem to grasp why that is the result. Can somebody give me the run down?

Comment: why are you using `e`? try `f`

Comment: Q: What were you expecting?  You wanted `%e` ([exponential format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)).  Q: Maybe you wanted `%f` instead?

Comment: Is your question actually "What does 1.23e+03 mean?"

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm obviously wrong, but I expected something like `1.23e+07` -- I don't understand where +03 is coming from.

Comment: That becomes a math problem... 1234.56789 = 1.23456789 x 1000 = 1.23e3.

Comment: @Jai That explains it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for exponential notation (`%e`) and you're getting it. If you want regular numerical formatting: `%8.2f`

In the case of exponential notation the format is always *[-]A.BBBe[+|-]CC*, like `1.29e+02` or `-3.98e-12`. In general terms this is short for *A.BBB x 10<sup>CC</sup>*, so `1.00e+01` is 10, `1.29e+02` is 129 and `-3.98e-04` is -0.000398.

You can always test this notation:

```
System.out.printf("n=%f", -3.98e-04);
```

Comment: Why does 1234.56789 formatted to %8.2e equivalent to 1.23e+03 in exponential notation? I'm aware of what i'm asking for, I just can't seem to understand why `n=1.23e+03` is the output.

Comment: That's what `%e` does as compared to `%f` and as far as I can tell [that's how it's always been](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) in any `printf`-style functions I've seen.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: And the `AA.BBB` is always between 1 and 9.9999, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Q: I expected something like 1.23e+07 -- I don't understand where +03 is coming from.

A: `1234 = 1.234 * 1000`.

1000 = 10^3

Hence `1.23e+03`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand now.